# Two Chrome users have differing results from ajax call

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I have an interface which is designed to encourage an admin user to select existing name entries where they exist but then make them editable.

The rendered code starts out like so

[image: before]

```
<td class="selectname" colspan="2" style="width: 220px; display: table-cell;">
<select name="PersonSelect" id="PersonSelect" style="font-size:10px">
<option></option>
<option value="123">Aamodt, Jodi</option>
...
```

And after a selection is made the select value is cleared and the TD hidden

```
<td class="selectname" colspan="2" style="width: 220px; display: none;">
```

And two new inputs are displayed:

```
<td class="entername" style="display: table-cell;"><input type="text" size="12" name="First" id="First" value="" class="required valid"></td>
<td class="entername" style="display: table-cell;"><input type="text" size="12" name="Last" id="Last" value="" class="required valid"></td>
```

[image: after]

The issue that is arising is that one of the admins is telling me that when he selects a person in the select menu that nothing changes - eg the text inputs do not appear and the select input does not disappear.

The user and myself are both accessing the page in Chrome.  The user is not especially technical but given screenshots was clear on the symptom.  JavaScript is not turned off in his Chrome as JavaScript validation routines are succeeding for the user during these same page loads.  The user and myself are loading the same datasets so this should not be an issue of breakage related to the data itself.

The ajax change function is below.

Any advice?

```
$("#PersonSelect").change(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: 'person_form_populater.php?person=' + $("#PersonSelect").val() + '&entity=' + $("#Entity").val(),
   dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
    if (data['found']) {
      alert('There is already a record linking that person to this entity');
      $('#First_' + data['found']).focus();
      var origColor = $('#bmformtable_' + data['found']).css("background-color");
      $('#bmformtable_' + data['found']).css("border", '0px solid #f00');
      $('#bmformtable_' + data['found']).animate({
        borderWidth: 5
      }, 2000, "linear", function() {
        $('#bmformtable_' + data['found']).animate({
        borderWidth: 0
      }, 2000, "linear", function() {

      });
      });
    } else {
      $('#togglelink').click();
      $('#First').val(data['First']);
      $('#Last').val(data['Last']);
      $('#Occupation').val(data['Occupation']);
      if (data['Gender'] == 'Male') {
        $("#Gender").attr('checked',true);
      } else if (data['Gender'] == 'Female') {
        $("#Gender2").attr('checked',true);
      } else {
        $("#Gender").attr('checked',false);
        $("#Gender2").attr('checked',false);
      }
      $('#Race').val(data['Race']);
      $('#Income').val(data['Income']);
      $('#Person').val(data['ID']);
    }
   }
});                
});
```

// Edit
This function allows user to "unselect" a loaded record and access the select menu again:

```
$("#togglelink,#togglelink2").click(function(){
    $('#PersonSelect option').attr('selected', false);
    $('#First').val('');
    $('#Last').val('');
    $('#Occupation').val('');
    $("#Gender").attr('checked',false);
    $("#Gender2").attr('checked',false);
    $('#Race').val('');
    $('#Income').val('');
    $('#Person').val('');
    $(".entername, .selectname, #togglelink, #togglelink2").toggle();                                
});
```

Comment: I think its a session / cookie issue, try cleaning everything and try a forced refresh, also, try this to find out any error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041148/show-proper-error-messages-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: What does `$('#togglelink').click();` do?

Comment: Thank you for the reply feco.  You are suggesting the user should access in Chrome "Settings > Advanced Settings > Privacy > Clear browsing data" and follow with a Ctrl F5?

Comment: yes, if that doesn't work, you can see the ajax errors here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041148/show-proper-error-messages-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: Carlos - have added that ajax function code to main post now.

Answer (score 1):

You said there are no errors in the users browser. I think there is an error but you are not seeing it.

log errors in the ajax call by doing the following:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
}).error(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
     console.log("error when using ajax" + data);
});
```

Comment: OK, have added and will get user to test.  I'm not seeing any errors reported though given previous performance that is not a surprise.  Anyway you can think of for me to trigger this and see the error reporting working?

Answer (score 1):

If the new feature was implemented on existing files it could be a Cache problem.

If asking the user to clear the cache is not an option, try appending a "version" to the javascript:

```
<script src="/js/yourjavascript.js?20130218" type="text/javascript">
```

The values after the ? wont affect the javascript but change the name of the resource, telling the browser that this file is not in the cache so he has to request it.

You could also check the server response on the console to make sure the server is replying correctly in both cases.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Other than jQuery there aren't external scripts loaded on the page.  The ajax code is in the page itself.

Comment: You need to make sure the server is responding correctly to both clients, i see you are using php, try an error_log($response) before your person_form_populater.php script returns. If the problem is not in the server response you can focus on possible client side issues. Assuming you have access to your servers error log